# can't open "/dev/mcelog" No such file or directory

Tags: yocto

When building yocto, I added the following:

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append += “ stressapptest fio iperf mcelog”`

All applications run correctly except mcelog, it shows:

```
can't open "/dev/mcelog" No such file or directory
```

This happened both in legacy mode and EFI mode.

Comment: are you building for x86 or x86_64 ? secondly, check if you have relvant options enabled in kernel defconfig CONFIG_X86_MCE=y CONFIG_X86_MCE_INTEL=y

Comment: I am budding x86_64, no idea how to modify kernel config, any hint?

Comment: try to find .config inkernel build tree and inspect it for above option if they exist and and are set to 'Y' then issue is something else perhaps character device is not created and we might have to create it manually using mknod cmd.

Comment: can we modify the .config in build folder directly then build again? will it work?

Comment: yes but execute `run.do_compile` script also in same dir, that should perhaps generate  a new kernel that you can quickly try and see if it helps. if it does then you have to create a patch and apply it permanently to defconfig so the change becomes permanent